# Place four tcolorbox boxes in a 2x2 grid spread evenly over page

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to spread four `tcolorbox` boxes EVENLY over an a4 page in a 2x2 grid. What I have so far is a grid but the four boxes are bunched up into one corner of the page. How do I spread them evenly over the page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{lmodern}% or any other vector / postscript font
\usepackage[default]{comfortaa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hoffset=-1in,voffset=-1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm,valign=center,nobeforeafter]
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.\\

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood \ldots \\

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.\\

Romans 3:22-26 

\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm,valign=center,nobeforeafter]
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.\\

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\ldots \\

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.\\

Romans 3:22-26 

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm,valign=center,nobeforeafter]
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.\\

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\ldots \\

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.\\

Romans 3:22-26 

\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=8cm,valign=center,nobeforeafter]
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.\\

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\ldots \\

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.\\

Romans 3:22-26 

\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Christian Thank you Christian! That is just what I needed.

Comment: Happy TeXing then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the `tcbraster` feature is made for such alignments here.

Defining a special `tcolorbox` for the content it is easy to setup a raster with `\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height]` etc. such that all inner `tcolorbox`es will have the same height.

There **must not** be any empty line between two inner `tcolorbox` usages!

- I don't assume that in reality the text won't be the same for all boxes (if that would be the case, a specialized box can be used as well), therefore I kept the text as is (and removed the `\\` )
- See the usage of the options to the inner box in order to change the local box.
- The spacing between the columns and rows of the raster can be adjusted with `raster column skip` and `raster row skip`, specified as options to the `tcbraster` environment.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{lmodern}% or any other vector / postscript font
\usepackage[default]{comfortaa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[hoffset=-1in,voffset=-1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
  valign=center,
  nobeforeafter,
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster halign=center, raster equal height=all]
\begin{mybox}
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.
\medskip

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\dots
\medskip

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.

\medskip
Romans 3:22-26 
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.
\medskip

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\dots
\medskip

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.

\medskip
Romans 3:22-26 
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.
\medskip

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\dots
\medskip

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.

\medskip
Romans 3:22-26 
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[colback=white!40!yellow]
We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ. And this is true for everyone who believes, no matter who we are.
\medskip

For everyone has sinned; we all fall short of God's glorious standard. Yet God, in his grace, freely makes us right in his sight. He did this through Christ Jesus when he freed us from the penalty for our sins. For God presented Jesus as the sacrifice for sin. People are made right with God when they believe that Jesus sacrificed his life, shedding his blood\dots
\medskip

God did this to demonstrate his righteousness, for he himself is fair and just, and he makes sinners right in his sight when they believe in Jesus.

\medskip
Romans 3:22-26 
\end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]